# Pandas - Data representation

Tags: python, pandas

I want to improve my data science skills, so I am working on a private project about paramedic events in my region. Therefore I have several Excel list from the year 2004 until 2021. Each excel list contains the same rows and columns - just different data. Just like
2004:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Y | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| Z | 7 | 8 | 9 |

2005:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 9 | 8 | 7 |
| Y | 6 | 5 | 4 |
| Z | 3 | 2 | 1 |

What is now the best way to represent these Data as pandas dataframe? Yes I can make a list of dataframes, but this isn't very pythonic.
I'm looking forward for your help ;-)
Regards Michael

Comment: concatenate them with a multiindex

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a list of the dataframes in order, use [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
lst = [df1, df2]
years = [2004, 2005]
df = pd.concat(lst, keys=years)
```

output:

```
        A  B  C
2004 X  1  2  3
     Y  4  5  6
     Z  7  8  9
2005 X  9  8  7
     Y  6  5  4
     Z  3  2  1
```

or, for a wide format:

```
pd.concat(lst, keys=years, axis=1)
```

output:

```
  2004       2005      
     A  B  C    A  B  C
X    1  2  3    9  8  7
Y    4  5  6    6  5  4
Z    7  8  9    3  2  1
```